# Problem with align inside tabular environment when using xcolor

Tags: tables, errors, color, align, colortbl

I'm trying to build a table with multiple numbered equations inside, hence I used the `align` environment. On the other hand, I need to color some cells, so I included the `xcolor` package with the `table` option. However, I can't build the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}}
    {\begin{align}
        S &= 4 \pi r ^2 \\
        V &= 4/3 \pi r^3
    \end{align}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`Misplaced \omit. \end{align}` is the error I get. Removing the `table` option makes it disappear. I tried to investigate the `xcolor` docs but it's not clear to me what that option does. How do you solve this?

**EDIT:** I apologize for the delay, had to finish the document swiftly and forgot I had posted the question here.
I see that my MWE turned up so minimal that it confused some of you, so have just modified it a little. I certainly needed the `align` environment, for I wanted to display several equations in one cell.

Comment: The problem is with the `colortbl` package

Comment: @egreg yes but...

Comment: if it's only for one line, why is `align` necessary?  (i ask because a lot of people use `align` when they really should be using `equation`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton we complain enough when people don't make examples minimal, can hardly complain when they do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This possibly does the right thing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}}
    {\makeatletter\CT@everycr{\the\everycr}\begin{align}
        S &= \pi r ^2
    \end{align}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could someone briefly explain what was breaking it and what does `\makeatletter\CT@everycr{\the\everycr}` do? Is it safe to replace `\usepackage{colortbl}` with my original `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`?

Comment: @Noitaenola you can use xcolor's table option (it is same as colortbl internally) what it is doing is setting the everycr hook that is run at the start of each table row so that it _just_ does the "normal" everycr without the commands that insert the coloured bands. They were messing up align.

Answer (score 1):

I used equation inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}}
  \cellcolor{yellow}\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\begin{equation}      S = \pi r ^2    \end{equation}\end{minipage}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**Edited**

After see David´s comment to use without `minipage` I tried and it worked too (must have made some mistake before). So here is another code and the result with and without using `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}}
  \cellcolor{yellow}\begin{equation}      S = \pi r ^2    \end{equation}\\ 
  \cellcolor{red}\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\begin{equation}      S = \pi r ^2    \end{equation}\end{minipage}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And the result. First row without minipage, second row with minipage. There´s difference on the vertical space.

[image]

Comment: I think it needs the approach by David Carlisle to make it work with `align`.

Comment: why would you use `minipage` here? You get the same output without it and just using `equation`.

Comment: David, you´re right. I must have made something wrong compiling without minipage. Tried again and it worked. I will edit the answer.