# beamer with tabu and cellcolor

Tags: beamer, tabu

I need to use `tabu` and `\cellcolor` in `beamer`.
So I added

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
```

to my LaTeX source.

But a previous part code

```
\begin{tabu}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
{
                   \begin{align*}
                     a &= b  \ \\
                     c &= d
                   \end{align*}
}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
{
                   \begin{align*}
                     A &= B  \ \\
                     C &= D
                   \end{align*}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabu}
```

is not working with the above two options.
This part of code was working before the above two options are added.

I tried to replace the part

```
\begin{align*}
  a &= b  \ \\
  c &= d
\end{align*}
```

to a simpler code, like just $ A $, i.e. without `align` in this part,
and it doesn't cause any problem.

**Question :** What cause the problem and how to fix it?

**Updated :** I found that the actual problem comes from `xcolor=table` option.
              If change it to `xcolor={}`, no longer error, but then `\cellcolor` won't work anymore.

```
% These two are needed for using \cellcolor with tabu in beamer.
% However, these will make the example code below not working.
%\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
%\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

% If not use the above two, the code below is fine.
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tabu}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}


\begin{tabu}{cc}
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
{
                   \begin{align*}
                     a &= b  \ \\
                     c &= d
                   \end{align*}
}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
{
                   \begin{align*}
                     A &= B  \ \\
                     C &= D
                   \end{align*}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabu}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213342/problem-with-align-inside-tabular-environment-when-using-xcolor

Comment: normally it should be possible to pass multiple options via `\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}` - but this combination gives an error. Do you really need `tabu` or would it be enough to position your minipages with e.g. `columns`?