# Conflict between [table]{xcolor} and {align} inside table

Tags: tables, color, align

I am trying to put some equations inside an `align` environment in a cell inside a table. However, when I activate the `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` option, my code inmediately crashes.

EDIT: I modified the question. Now, the code below works.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% librería para definir funciones matemáticas
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

% definiendo los colores
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % con la opción para colorear las tablas

% Para las tablas
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{%
                |
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|%     Todo esto es para que centre horizontal
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|%    y verticalmente en la celda
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{6cm}%
                |}
            \hline\hline
            \textbf{Caso}           & \textbf{Apoyo} & \textbf{Ecuaciones} \\ 
            \hline\hline
            Rodillo intermedio &
            & 
            {\makeatletter\CT@everycr{\the\everycr}
             %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213342/problem-with-align-inside-tabular-environment-when-using-xcolor/213347#213347
                \begin{align*}
                      v_i(a) &= \Delta_a \\
                      v_{i+1}(a) &= \Delta_a \\
                      \theta_i(a) &= \theta_{i+1}(a) \\    
                      M_i(a) &= M_{i+1}(a) + m   
                \end{align*}
                \begin{center}
                    \hrulefill
                \end{center} 
                $R_y = V_{i+1}(a) - V_{i}(a) - f$ 
            }
        \\ \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213347/2388

Comment: as per the answer linked to by @UlrikeFischer, add `\makeatletter\CT@everycr{\the\everycr}\makeatother` in place of the `%` which follows the `{` right above `\begin{align*}`.  Your question appears to be a duplicate indeed of the question whose answer Ulrike Fischer gave the link to.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can also be avoided with use `aligned` math environment instead of `align*. By using` tabullaray` package for writing your table the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
% definiendo los colores
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % con la opción para colorear las tablas
% Para las tablas
\usepackage{tabularray}
% librería para definir funciones matemáticas
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, wd=2cm] X[0.8, c] X[c, mode=dmath]},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
             rowsep=5pt
             }
Caso    &   Apoyo   &   Ecuaciones  \\
\SetCell[r=2]{h}    Rodillo intermedio 
        &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}               
                    &   \begin{aligned}
                    v_i(a)      & = \Delta_a        \\
                    v_{i+1}(a)  & = \Delta_a        \\
                    \theta_i(a) & = \theta_{i+1}(a) \\
                    M_i(a)      & = M_{i+1}(a) + m
                        \end{aligned}                       \\
        &           &   R_y = V_{i+1}(a) - V_{i}(a) - f     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I a wee bit change your table design.